# OpenSuse Tumbleweed: How to run a bash script on startup?

Tags: bash, shell-script, startup

I'm trying to a run a .sh file on startup of a rPi3B+ running openSuse Tumbleweed JeOS. The script is really simple and looks like this:

`node /home/user_name/path/to/the/file.js`

here are two links I tried to follow:

https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/428743-How-to-run-script-at-startup
https://www.suse.com/c/easy-running-scripts-boot-and-shutdown/
https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/startup/html/book.opensuse.startup/cha.adm.shell.html

How how to go about this?

Edit: I also just tried following along to this one without any luck either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973777/how-to-run-a-shell-script-at-startup#12973826

My `startServer` script in `/etc/init.d` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
# ScriptName=startServer
node /home/user-name/server.js &
```

Answer (score 0):

`/etc/init.d/after.local`

create this file and from within call your `script.sh`
it will execute as root.

Otherwise you can call it via `su -c '/path/yourscript.sh' username` where *username* is whatever valid user account.

**After the system is fully booted** if `/etc/init.d/after.local` exists then whatever is in it will be run.  You can `chmod 600 /etc/init.d/after.local` and `chown root.root /etc/init.d/after.local` if you are concerned about security.

**your StartServer script in /etc/init.d looks like this:**

`/etc/init.d/StartServer.sh`

**it contains**

```
#!/bin/sh
# ScriptName=startServer
node /home/user-name/server.js &
```

**create `/etc/init.d/after.local` and its contents is simply**

```
/etc/init.d/StartServer.sh
```

1. after system is fully booted, the last step [this is a suse thing] it will try to execute the file `/etc/init.d/after.local` if it exists
2. you manually create `/etc/init.d/after.local` and put `/etc/init.d/StartServer.sh` in it
3. your StartServer.sh script gets run after the system is fully booted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by call from within? Do you mean to include a line in the `after.local` file for each `.sh` file? Do these `.sh` files need to be contained in the `init.d` folder? Could you perhaps give an example of what this "call looks like"? Thank you!

Comment: added clarification to above

Comment: realize you can call anything from `/etc/init.d/after.local` it does not need to be a `.sh` script.

Answer (score 0):

openSUSE, both Leap and Tumbleweed, have switched to `systemd` long time ago. There should be nothing under `/etc/init.d`.

All services should come with `systemd` startup templates `*.service` located under `/usr/lib/systemd/system` (if not, you can easily create your own `*myserver*.service` under `/etc/systemd/system`).

In the respective .service file, add a line

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sh -c "node /home/user-name/server.js &"
```

after the `ExecStart=` line that starts the service. Also consider stopping your server.js through a corresponding `ExecStopPre=` entry.